# How did the ending happen from Neil's perspective?

Tags: plot-explanation, tenet

I am trying to figure out the scene near the finale of *Tenet* where Neil unlocks the door and gets shot in the face.

I can't really see the flow where he opens and holds the door and the protagonist walks in and fights the bad guy.
Can you tell the series of events as Neil sees them happen till he gets shot?

**UPDATE**

If I am not wrong, I see it like this:

Neil was running down towards the door, both the protagonist and his mate are inside with the door locked fighting the bad guy, then, he unlocks the door and walks in and stands behind the door. The protagonist's mate comes out of the room, then the protagonist, then he closes the room, then he look back to get shot in the face.

But this doesn't make sense, if he wanted to unlock the door when he was running down, they were already in fighting the bad guy!!!!!

Comment: Yes, that's probably the only sequence of events that I can't get a full understanding of.

Comment: Actually, I've been having trouble sleeping because of this. Perhaps Neil didn't have to pick the lock. He died in vain.

Comment: @Mocas, since the film is on Prime, I rewatched this scene over many times and have re-done my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this doesn't make sense, if he wanted to unlock the door when he was running down, they were already in fighting the bad guy!!!!!

At that point, Neil has already been to the final sequence where the end of the world has been just prevented and Ives was about to shoot Neil and the Protagonist to make sure no one knows the algorithm. After Ives then changes his mind, Neil says that he is "the only one who could've got that door open in time" and so that he has to go back to do it.

So he does. Being inverted and going backwards in time, Neil understands that the order of events has to be the opposite. Yes he sees the Protagonist and Ives already fighting Volkov behind the door, but a few moments ahead *for* him (or a few moments *before* for them) he will need to keep the door open to let them "out" ("in" for them). So he does exactly that — finally locking the two of them outside and, unfortunately, catching the Volkov's bullet which was purported for the Protagonist.

Snapshots in normal order (time going forwards, as shown in the film):

Neil has just stood up and been (un)shot by Volkov:

[image]

Neil grabs the gate:

[image]

Neil has opened the gate and let the Protagonist in:

[image]

Neil keeps the gate open while Ives gets up and walks in too:

[image]

Neil walks out of the gate closing it behind him while Ives picks up the pistol:

[image]

Ives turns back and sees Neil shutting the gate:

[image]

Ives sees Neil running backwards:

[image]

Note that Ives was lying knocked down by the first Volkov's bullet that had hit his helmet before the Protagonist started talking to Sator over the phone — up until Neil lets them in, so Ives could not pick the lock at all.

Comment: Neil never faces the gate in this scene. He doesn't lock (or un-lock) the gate.

Comment: @John See the added screenshots and perhaps re-watch the scene. We can't see how he locks/unlocks the gate but we definitely see that he opens/closes it. So guess he manages to pick/unlock it instantly somehow.

Comment: Actually, there is a very short part of this scene where you see the lock on the door moves.

Comment: @Greendrake - that instant lock-picking appears to be a gaping hole in this scene. Neil's not even looking at the lock  . It's under a second that the gate opens soon as Neil is un-shot. Ives might be on the ground right after the bullet... but he was trying for a while to pick that lock .. perhaps he managed to unlock the gate just before the bullet. Seems more palatable than Neil's magic lock opening. But there seems to be some execution flaw in this sequence for sure.

Comment: @John Neil is a super-duper professional, he does not even need to look at locks to unlock them 

Comment: @Greendrake haha... that's not what it seemed like when they were running through the corridors devoid of air . Perhaps Ives slipped in the key card in Neil's back pocket without telling... him before he inverted himself. . Part - 2: Rise of Ives.

Comment: I think Neil did lock the gate from the inside, meaning unlocking it for P and Ives.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer - The lock didn't need picking it was an auto-lock gate.

In that scene Ives was trying to pick the lock (unsuccessfully).
Just after Inverted-Neil un-dies and stands up, he swings the gate open (he doesn't unlock it or pick it), Ives and The Protagonist enter the holding area.

Inverted-Neil doesn't touch the lock. Inverted-Neil, from his perspective, held the gate and then swung it shut. He does not face the lock, get on his knees, or attempt to pick it. From Inverted-Neil's perspective he shut the gate which auto-locked.

Because it's an auto-locking gate, from the forward perspective, the gate un-auto-locked and Inverted-Neil simply swung the gate open. Neil doesn't pick the lock.

From Inverted-Neil's perspective this is what happened:

1. Inverted-Neil enters the tunnel. Runs up to the end to see that The Protagonist and Ives are already in.
2. Inverted-Neil enters and holds the gate.
3. Inverted-Neil notices Sator's man is being un-shot while holding a gun.
4. Inverted-Neil swings the gate closed (which auto-locks) and gets in front of Sator's man
5. Inverted-Neil takes the bullet (*bullet enters the back of Inverted-Neil's head, and leaves from the front, and enters the gun*)

In the end, though Neil states, "*I'm the only one who could've got
that door open in time, right, Ives?*" and Ives responds saying, "*I don't know any locksmiths as good as you*" ... there was no need of a locksmith in this case as it was an auto-locking door. Anybody could have gone and shut that gate when inverted. Ives says what he did because *what has happened has happened*, it **has** to be Neil who shuts the gate and in the process take that bullet. Only if Neil dies, will The Protagonist live, and this has already happened. Neil being there also un-auto-locks (without picking) the gate allowing access to Ives and The Protagonist.

Comment: The issues with this answer is that Ives asked the protagonist at the final scene "How did you get that lock open", protagonist replied "It wasn't me".

Comment: @mocas Which Ives says because he knows Neil needs a reason to be inverting himself to head back to the bunker. He knows Neil's being there saves The Protagonist, not to unlock the gate. If not for that, Tenet can't exist. If Ives says the truth about the gate, Neil will have no reason to invert himself.

Comment: I think Neil was unlucky on being shot, as per the answer here https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/112214/how-did-neil-know-that-volkov-is-going-to-shoot-the-protagonist

Comment: If Neil reached the bunker and saw that the gate was already opened, he would simply bail thinking "I'm not needed here", but he still goes to the gate and on to the other side realizing that unlocking the gate is not why he's there, but something more. Perhaps he intercepted the bullet by mistake in the confusion, but Neil had nothing to do with the gate as he goes nowhere near the lock. Let me edit the answer a little.

Comment: @mocas yes, Neil doesn't intercept the bullet as a plan. I believe he goes for the goons gun and in the struggle ends up being shot. I think I can sleep again!

Comment: Neil reached the bunker already aware that his role was to open the gate to let the two guys in. He came there reverted from the final scene up on the ground where he says that he has to go back. The gate was actually shut at all times except when Neil held it open.

Comment: @greendrake, I think the point is "picking the lock" to open the gate. Neil is an expert lock picker. Ives mentions that Neil is the expert lockpicker which is why Neil decides to invert himself. In that scene you'll observe that Neil doesn't ever pick the lock (from either side of the gate). It's a gate, so once shut it needs to be locked by Neil (which in actual flow of time will be unlocked). We don't see Neil doing anything with the lock. Only shutting the gate doesn't accomplish anything; it needed locking as well, and that doesn't happen.

Comment: @MovieMe It does not happen indeed, it seems as if he opens/closes the gate like it is not locked at all. Nevertheless, he does it whereas _the other two could not_, which means he does in fact use his expertise somehow e.g. a hacker's card which unlocks the gate on tap or something.

Comment: I've watched multiple animated presentations of the scene, and it appears that Ives has nothing to do with unlocking the gate. (Ives was downed when the gate was unlocked.) All of them show Neil unlocking it, which makes more sense given the dialogue: "I'm the only one who could've got that door open in time, right, Ives?" "Well, I don't know any locksmiths as good as you." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIK9b3vMLxg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3ATr94lXIk

Comment: @MovieMe No one "unlocked" the door. From Neill's perspective, when he run into the tunnel, he saw the door already unlocked. He only needed to "lock" the door. Th door perhaps locked automatically when he locked/shut them. From Ives and TP perspective it looked like Neill "unlocked" it.

Comment: @galacticninja, Neil doesn't go anywhere near the lock either. He doesn't face the lock even for a fraction of a second. All he did was swing the gate open/close based on perspective. Didn't need no locksmith for that.

Comment: @John I just rewatched the scene where Neil got reversed-shot. Neil was near the lock. The unlocking/reverse-locking was shown in the movie for about one second. We can see the latch of the gate moving before inverted-Neil unlocked/reverse-locked it. What happened was inverted-Neil "locked" the gate from his perspective (ergo, *un*locking it for the non-inverted/forward TP and Ives).

Comment: @galacticninja - Edited the entire answer based on inputs from the various comment and after going through that scene over again. Fact remains that there is not a moment that Neil does anything to the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Inverted-Neil, from his perspective, opened the *un*locked gate, entered, held the gate open, then *locked* the gate, *un*locking it for the non-inverted/forward TP and Ives. He then died after being shot by Volkov after unlocking/reverse-locking the gate.

In the scene where Neil got shot, we see the gate latch or bolt moving (shown for around one second only) showing that the gate was unlocked/reverse-locked by inverted-Neil.

Neil approaches the gate and then enters the unlocked gate.
[image] [image]

Neil goes to the left side and holds the gate open.
[image] [image]
[image] [image]

Neil closes and locks the gate.
[image] [image]

Neil gets shot by Volkov.
[image] [image]

The latch or bolt (encircled in red in this screenshot) moves, signifying that the gate is unlocked (or locked, in inverted POV).
[image]

The part where Neil gets shot is shown at around [04:30 in this Youtube video of the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=270&v=aIlKsyD6rSs).

Animated presentations of the scene:

- [3D visualization of the gate scene in Tenet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIK9b3vMLxg)
- [TENET Hypocenter Scene / Neil / Stalsk-12 – Animated Interpretation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3ATr94lXIk)

---

[Another answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/111929/1006) here suggests that it was Ives that unlocked the gate. This is contradicted by dialogue among the Protagonist, Ives, and Neil.

> Ives: How'd you get that lock open?
> The Protagonist: Wasn't me.

> Neil: I'm the only one who could've got that door open in time, right, Ives?
> Ives: Well, I don't know any locksmiths as good as you.

Ives has nothing to do with unlocking the gate. In fact, he was downed while the gate was being unlocked/reverse-locked by Neil and is not near the lock at all.

---

Some comments in the other answers: [[1]](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/112248/1006), [[2]](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/111929/1006) - raise the issue of how Neil "instantly" picked the lock or why no lockpicking was shown in the scene.

To use Ives' words — you have to "stop thinking in linear terms."

Related dialogue from the scene where the Protagonist reverse-shoots a bullet:

> The Protagonist: Why does it feel so strange?
> Barbara (the Tenet scientist): You're not shooting the bullet, you're catching it.
> The Protagonist: Whoa.

In this case, inverted-Neil is not unlocking the gate (in linear terms), he's *locking* it. Locking a gate is much faster than lockpicking a gate. This is why inverted-Neil wasn't shown to be picking the gate's lock.

Related dialogue from the scene where the Protagonist tries to catch an inverted bullet:

> Barbara: You have to have dropped it.
> The Protagonist: How can it move before I touch it?
> Barbara: From your point of view, you caught it. But from the bullet's point of view, you dropped it.
> The Protagonist: But cause comes before effect.
> Barbara: No, that's just the way we see time.
> ...
> The Protagonist: Instinct. Got it.

This shows how good Neil is at lockpicking, that even if inverted, he can unlock locks by instinct.

Comment: Neil is also shown as a great lockpicker in the Freeport scene, when he unlocks some of the doors while the Protagonist falied.

Answer (score 0):

I *partially* agree with MovieMe's answer. It was an autolocking gate. However, Neil **DID** unlock the gate (or pick the lock if you will), just not when we all think he had to. In the forward timeline, Ives (after regaining conciousness and passing the gate) saw Neil closing the gate behind them and reverse-running away, which means that in Neil's perspective (reversed timeline), he **HAD** to pick that lock when he arrived at the gate (because it autolocked, remember?) just to get in and hold the gate open for his mates to get out.